# Does Goolge Slides have a 'next slide' event or trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

Does Google Slides have a 'next slide' event or trigger?  PowerPoint (via Microsoft has a next-side event/trigger that a PowerShell script can listen for, so you can automate a task as each slide is changed in PowerPoint.  We use this to control different cameras during a presentation, so for example, when the speaker, changes to a new slide, the camera input for the slide deck is set to full screen, waits 30 seconds, then the camera focused on the presenter is set to full screen.  This means that no manual camera switching is required, no human action required.  This works well via PowerPoint, PowerShell, and our camera control system, that has a API/SDK we linked to PowerShell.  I am looking for the same concept with Google Slides in some manner.

Comment: According to Documentation it only has an onOpen event: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to trigger this event but hey I do believe this would be a nice addition, someone seems to have [already submitted a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180951649) for triggers for slide changes both going forward and backwards it would be great if you could also vote for it, here is the button where you can do so:

[image: vote here]